# How do you go from the Old Portal to the New Portal in Azure?

Tags: azure-sql-database

How do I navigate from the Old Azure Dashboard to the New Azure Dashboard?

SQL Azure has a new, default front-end user interface and an older version.  I have been able to navigate to the older version UI but now I do not know how to get back to the newer version so that I can add some t-sql commands on my database.

This is how the older UI (the one I am stuck on) looks:
[image: [IMG]http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/AZURE/oldwindow.png[/IMG]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the bottom of your screenshot, the first hyperlink on the leftmost says: "Visit the Preview Portal"